# PHP file returns blank when executed through CLI

Tags: php, api, command-line-interface, webrtc, ratchet

I am trying to learn WebRTC in php and have found an App in github: https://github.com/amirsanni/Video-Call-App

In order to run that app i have to run the server.php through command line. I am precisely following what the dev said i.e navigate to the directory and run **php server.php** however when i run it the CLI returns nothing. It looks something like this:

> P.S: Things i tried till now:
>
> - executing other php files returns atleast errors instead of forever    blinking cursor.
> - tried running from browser but no success, it keeps loading and shows blank.

[image]

Comment: Keep reading that file: *"Run the app from your browser at: http://localhost/video-call-app/"*. That's just a server, it's now opened a port on your machine and is waiting for you to connect via browser.

Comment: What are you expecting it to return? The server appears to be running.

Comment: Why do you think that it is not running ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I dont think it can be ran from the browser, since i already tried it and it doesnt load it keeps loading

Comment: Did you check security settings if it can be executed by another user or group? Are the error settings on in case there is an error? Or could it be that there should be a session created for it to work?

Comment: @l'L'l If its running then why do i get object not found error?

Comment: @CyrilJoudieh If its security related problem then i wont be able to execute another php files, as i can execute other files.

Comment: @IstiyakTailor: Why is that not mentioned in your question? I would recommend editing your question and include any relevant error messages.

Comment: @l'L'l I know but I am new to programming and don't know much, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it, that It wasn't supposed to be returning anything.
Now the reason why I asked it doesn't return anything because when I run localhost:8000 it says 404 not found, so I thought maybe the server isn't running that's why it cannot find the file path.

So the problem was when I extracted the folder ( downloaded from the link in my question ) the folder name had a prefix with "-master" that's why it cannot find the path, removing it solved the problem.